# Simple LINQ count, or so I thought

Tags: c#, linq, entity

I am trying to get a count of this:

```
Model.Version.Where(model => model.revision != Model.revision).Count();
```

However it tells me in VS that I cannot use Lambda expressions.

The model is of type Documents, which is keyed to Version.

I need the count of any documents in the version table for the model documents where the revision is greater than the model revision.

This will either be a 0 or a 1, could sometimes be higher than 1 I suppose.

What am I doing wrong?

```
if (Model.Version.Where(model => model.revision > Model.revision).Count() > 0)
{
     // do something
}
```

Comment: Is "Version" a collection of objects?

Comment: Use `Any` instead of `Count()>0`.

Comment: @JonLaMarr yes it could be 0 or many.

Comment: Why is it you can not use lambda expressions? Wrong framework version or do you have an error?

Comment: I'd second Tim Schmelter then. Using .Any() is the same as checking for .Count > 0. Does that work?

Comment: You can't use lambda expressions inside the VS debugger (e.g. in the watch window), but the code looks fine.

Comment: Great that your question got answered, but it does not make sense that `Any` would work and `Count` would not.

Comment: @gunr2171 I'm not sure why it wasn't working, I had it in an if/else statement with Count()  and it would always display true, I switch ot to Any() boolean and it is working.  Maybe something small i missed with Count().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have said, your real code should be fine: it sounds like the problem was *only* that you were trying to execute this in the debugger instead of in normal code. Personally I'm always somewhat leery of trying to take things too far in the debugger - it can be useful of course, but if things behave unexpectedly, I'd always see whether the same code works as part of a real program, rather than assuming there's something fundamentally wrong with the approach. The debugger has to work under rather different constraints than the normal compilation and execution process.

Likewise, as others have said, it's better to use `Any()` than `Count() > 0`. However, cleaner yet is to use the overload of `Any` accepting a predicate:

```
if (Model.Version.Any(model => model.revision > Model.revision))
{
    ...
}
```

Note however that that's not quite the same as your initial predicate, which was asking for any versions which had a *different* revision rather than a *higher* revision. You may want:

```
if (Model.Version.Any(model => model.revision != Model.revision))
{
    ...
}
```

It's worth noting that in LINQ to Objects, using `Any` can have very real performance benefits over using `Count() > 0`. In providers which convert the query to a different form (e.g. SQL) there may be no *performance* benefit, but there's a *clarity* benefit in saying exactly what you're interested in - you don't really care about the count, you only care if there are *any* matching items.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to add a watch for it which didn't work, but with Count() > 0 it would always evaluate to true even when it shouldn't.  But when I used Any() I would they get the correct true/false visuals as expected.  I would have thought the County() should work, so maybe it was just something tiny i missed and when i made the Any() changes I fixed whatever was wrong as well without knowing.